# Irreducible components of the Steinberg variety are conormal bundles - reference?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory

The (partial) Springer resolution is defined as a map $\mu: T^*\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{N}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the partial flag variety consisting of $n$-step partial flags of $\mathbb{C}^d$, and $\mathcal{N}$ a set of nilpotent operators $\mathcal{N} = \{X \in \text{End}(\mathbb{C}^d) : X^n = 0\}$. There's a characterisation of the cotangent bundle of the flag variety as the set of pairs $T^*\mathcal{F} = \{(X, F_\bullet) \in \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{F} : XF_i \subset F_{i-1} \text{ for all } i\}$.

Using this characterisation, the Steinberg variety is the fibred product $Z = T^*\mathcal{F} \times_\mathcal{N} T^*\mathcal{F}$, alternatively written as the set of triples $Z = \{(X, F_\bullet, F_\bullet'):\dots\}$. There is a standard result that this variety is the union of conormal bundles to the $GL_d(\mathbb{C})$-diagonal orbits in $\mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{F}$, see e.g.  Chriss-Ginzburg Prop 4.1.6 or 3.3.4.

On the other hand, the Bruhat decomposition tells us that these diagonal orbits are parametrised by elements of the corresponding Weyl group (in this case, $S_n$ the symmetric group). It is another standard fact that the *irreducible components* of the Steinberg variety are the (closures of the) conormal bundles to these orbits, see e.g. Chriss-Ginzburg Corollary 3.3.5.

I'm looking for either a proof of this result, or at the very least a good moral reason for why this should be true.

Comment: This is answered by Sam Gunningham over at MO - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371596/reference-irreducible-components-of-the-steinberg-variety-are-conormal-bundles?noredirect=1#comment940503_371596